# How do I break a loop without the if-condition in the results

Tags: java, while-loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tykinkuula {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner lukija = new Scanner(System.in);

    double highest = 0;

    int seconds = 0;
    double height = 0;

    System.out.println("Syötä tykinkuulan lähtönopeus: ");
    double startspeed = Double.parseDouble(lukija.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Syötä painovoima: ");
    double gravity = Double.parseDouble(lukija.nextLine());

    System.out.println(seconds + "\t" + height + "\t" + startspeed);

    while (true) {
        if (height < 0.0) {
            break;
        }

        height = height + startspeed;
        seconds = seconds + 1;
        startspeed = startspeed - gravity; 

        if (height > highest) {
            highest = height;
        }

        System.out.println(seconds + "\t" + height + "\t" + startspeed);            
    }

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Tykinkuulan suurin korkeus oli " + highest);

}
```

This is a code for a calculator that gives me the speed and height of a canonball every second. You input a desired starting speed and gravity, and then run the code.

When I run this code, it gives me 3 columns, seconds, height and speed.

The loop is supposed to end before the canonball hits the ground, so basically before **height = 0**. But when I run the code it gives me a negative height, but I need the program to only show results of when the ball is in the air.

So, how do I remove the negative result?

Comment: It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: while (height>=0.0)

Comment: where do you increment the variable, "highest"? It will always be 0 in your case.

Comment: @akshayapandey doesn't help at all. The calculation where `heigth` becomes negative, happens during the loop

Comment: yes..and when height becomes -ve, the condition ensure that the loop terminates...that is what if block does and this will ensure same behavior

Answer (score 1):

Simply move

```
if (height < 0.0) {
    break;
}
```

after the calculation. Since you only check once it is below 0, you need to check after calculating the next step. Currently you check at the start of the loop, where `height` still has the value from the previous iteration (0), while the next calculation outputs a negative number